# Full example of installing Bookstack via Docker with NGINX reverse proxy as a subdomain

Tags: php, docker, nginx

Have been trying to find a good example of someone who has successfully created a bookstack as a subdirectory on a domain with the use of APP_URL. There have been one or two examples in the web but none of them appear to work on the reverse proxy. Bookstack can happily be accessed directly via its IPADDRESS:PORT via HTTP but none of the docker/nginx installations to a subdirectory appear to work.The issue seems to be 404 on any CSS elements - possibly because the APP_URL parameter does not correctly map them to the subdirectory domain element (eg `http://www.anythingasdomain.com/bookstack`). Any help appreciated.

The following links have been tried:-

1. https://github.com/BookStackApp/BookStack/issues/1882
2. https://mangolassi.it/topic/18120/nginx-serverblock-for-bookstack
3. https://github.com/BookStackApp/BookStack/issues/2420
4. https://discourse.linuxserver.io/t/bookstack-behind-letsencrypt-subfolder/1160
5. https://meta.discourse.org/t/subfolder-support-with-docker/30507

Answer (score 0):

This is how official documentation say a "Sub Directory" should be setup

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

...

# BookStack Configuration
Alias "/bookstack" "/var/www/bookstack/public"

<Directory "/var/www/bookstack/public">
  Options FollowSymlinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted

  RewriteEngine On
  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/bookstack">
  AllowOverride None
  Require all denied
</Directory>
# End BookStack Configuration

...
```

Here is a link to that for more details

[Sub Directory Setup](https://www.bookstackapp.com/docs/admin/subdirectory-setup/)